# audio element not valid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I'm creating a audio player with visualizer.
But currently when I press the input to start the audio player my debug console returns:

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no
>   supported source was found.

What I'm currently doing is setting the whole audio element up in JS / jQuery:

```
var bins = 512;
var backgroundColour = "#2C2E3B";
var barColour = "#EC1A55";
var floorLevel = 32;

var audioContext;
var audioBuffer;
var audioAnalyserNode;
var initialized = false;
var songText = "";
var textSize;
var freqLookup = [];
var canvasContext;
var isStream = true;
var canvasWidth;
var canvasHeight;
var src;

var audioElement;
var isPlaying = false;
var volume = 1;

function play() {

  audioElement = document.createElement('audio');

  // Opus support check stuff
  var streamEndpoint = 'http://**.**.**.**:8003/stream';
  var canPlayOpus = (typeof audioElement.canPlayType === "function" && audioElement.canPlayType('audio/ogg; codecs="opus"') !== "");
  if(volume > 1) {
      volume = volume / 100;
  }

  audioElement.src         = streamEndpoint;
  audioElement.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
  audioElement.volume      = volume;
  audioElement.play();

  isPlaying = true;
  setUpCanvas(audioElement);
}

function pause() {

    audioElement.pause();
    audioElement.currentTime = 0;
    audioElement.src = '';
    isPlaying = false;
}

function setUpCanvas(audioElement){
    try {
        initCanvas(document.getElementById("canvas"));
        if(typeof audioContext === 'undefined') {
            audioContext = new AudioContext();
        }
        if (audioElement) {
            isStream = true;
            setupAudioApi(true, audioElement);
        }
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}

function setupAudioApi(isStream, audioElement) {
    //var src;
    if (isStream){
        if(typeof src === 'undefined'){
            src = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(audioElement);
            audioContext.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
            audioAnalyserNode = audioContext.createAnalyser();
            audioAnalyserNode.fftSize = bins * 4;
            src.connect(audioAnalyserNode);
            audioAnalyserNode.connect(audioContext.destination);
        }
    }

    if (!isStream) {
        src.start();
    }
    initialized = true;
    initFreqLookupTable();
}

function initCanvas(canvasElement) {
    canvasContext = canvasElement.getContext('2d');
    canvasElement.width = canvasElement.clientWidth;
    canvasElement.height = canvasElement.clientHeight;
    canvasWidth = canvasElement.width;
    canvasHeight = canvasElement.height;
    requestAnimationFrame(paint);
}

function getFreqPoint(start, stop, n, binCount) {
    return start * Math.pow(stop / start, n / (binCount - 1));
}

function initFreqLookupTable() {
    var lastPoint = 0;
    var bins = audioAnalyserNode.frequencyBinCount;
    for(var i = 0; i < bins / 2; i++) {
        //Scale to perceived frequency distribution
        var newFreq = getFreqPoint(20, 20000, i * 2, bins);
        var point = Math.floor(bins * newFreq / 20000);
        while (point <= lastPoint) {
            point++;
        }
        lastPoint = point;
        freqLookup.push(point);
    }
}

//Render some fancy bars
function paint() {
    requestAnimationFrame(paint);

    if(!initialized) {
        alert('Er is iets fout gegaan');
        return false;
    }
    canvasContext.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
    canvasContext.fillStyle = backgroundColour;
    canvasContext.fillRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

    var bins = audioAnalyserNode.frequencyBinCount;
    var data = new Uint8Array(bins);
    audioAnalyserNode.getByteFrequencyData(data);
    canvasContext.fillStyle = barColour;

    for(var i = 0; i < bins; i++) {
        var point = freqLookup[i];
        //Pretty much any volume will push it over 128 so we set that as the bottom threshold
        //I suspect I should be doing a logarithmic space for the volume as well
        var height = Math.max(0, (data[point] - floorLevel));
        //Scale to the height of the bar
        //Since we change the base level in the previous operations, 256 should be changed to 160 (i think) if we want it to go all the way to the top
        height = (height / (256 - floorLevel)) * canvasHeight * 0.8;
        var width = Math.ceil(canvasWidth / ((bins / 2) - 1));
        canvasContext.fillRect(i * width, canvasHeight - height, width, height);
    }
}
```

The stream is in audio/mpeg format, it does load when I simply create an audio element in HTML with a src.

Can someone help me clarify and find the solution to the DOMException I'm getting. I have been searching other cases of this error but the fixes there didn't resolve the problem.

Comment: what format is your stream in? Not all formats are supported by all browsers. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats

Comment: @ADyson Updated my question, info is now provided.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the audio tag like this:

```
var audio = new Audio('audio_file.mp3');
```

And try setting the type:

```
audio.type = "audio/mpeg";
```

I think that will fix your problem.

This creates an  element, identical to the one you use in your code.
 I suggest you put an extension on your stream.

I know this way works, and I don't know why the other way doesn't.

Comment: @MoshiRadio is the stream URL from a different domain and/or port than your page? If so you'll only be able to use it from JavaScript if the server allows CORS (cross-origin) requests, which it sounds like it might not.

Comment: @ADyson Yes the stream url comes from a different domain. Does the webhost have to allow CORS or the stream server?

Comment: it's the server hosting the stream URL which has to allow it via setting the correct response headers. If it's not your server then you have no control over it.

Comment: Is the stream a file, or a stream (file keeps changing)?

Comment: Using the type attribute, you may be able to "force" it to play mpeg.